# Does Postgres use local resources when connecting to a server?

Tags: postgresql, remote-access

I am new to Postgres and wanted to understand if i make a remote server for Postgres and use PGadmin to connect to the remote server, will it use local resources to run the queries?

I tried it on a user machine here and it seems to be the case and would like the queries submitted to be run on the server itself and not consume local resources. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks 
Saurabh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the query is run on the server. However the download and the display of the results can take some time and can take ressources on the client, depending on the size of the result set.

Comment: Thanks. But i realized that the memory usage was too high even when i was trying to update only 400,000 records in a table. It maxed out at 8 GB (local machine capacity and then errored out). Why would this happen then.

Comment: Do you use pgAdmin III or pgAdmin 4 ?

Comment: pgAdmin 4 is young and maybe not very optimized (it's a web app on your desktop if I understand correctly). Try PgAdmin III, it's a native app and should be more efficient... though I can't see why an UPDATE query would slow a client...

Comment: Thank you mdag02. I see that the resource utilization is better in pgadmin3